# How to echo counter to file in bash

Tags: bash, count, counter

The content of file:

```
$ cat count.txt
0
```

This is my script:

```
counter=`cat count.txt`
value=`let counter++`
echo $value > count.txt
```

But the syntax is wrong...

Could you help me over this thread? How can I increase counter and echo it to file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BASH's `(( and ))` construct for arithmetic operations:

```
echo 0 > count.txt
counter=$(<count.txt)

((counter++))
echo $counter > count.txt
cat count.txt
1
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
value=$((++counter))
```

to use `let`

```
let value=++counter
```